# $X_{T-}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{T-}$ measurable

Tags: stochastic-processes

By definition, $\mathcal{F}_{T-}=\mathcal{F}_0 \vee \sigma(A\cap \{ t<T\}, A \in \mathcal{F}_t, t \in [0,\infty[)$.

[image]

Why is $X_{T-}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{T-}$ measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y$ is predictable, then $Y_T$ is ${\cal F}_{T-}$-measurable. The left-limit process $Y$, as defined above, is left-continuous and adapted, hence predictable.

See [this source](https://almostsuremath.com/2009/11/23/sigma-algebras-at-a-stopping-time/), Lemma 1, for a proof using a monotone class argument.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I'm glad it helps.